# QtStringList : indexOf with a string "abc\ntest" failed. "\n" inside the string are two normal characters

Tags: c++, qt, indexof

Try to find the string `"abc\ntest"` inside a QStringList (with indexOf). `"\n"` are two normal characters in the search-string.
If i change the search-pattern into  `"abc\\ntest"` I find the string. 
Why?

Comment: sorry, one error :  If i change the string in "abc\\ntest" if find the string

Comment: Despite the downvote, this is not a bad question.  You have to know the phrase "escape sequence" to find the answer.  The tldr is that your C++ compiler treats `"\n" `as a *single* character (the newline character).  Similarly `"\\"` is a single character - the backslash character.

Comment: ... and for a very similar reason, the text formatter in Stack Overflow questions treats backslash specially ... unless they are inside back-ticks (which also make them look like code).